# Alternative functions to gDistance from rgeos package in sf or terra package

Tags: r

I need to use the `gDistance` function to calculate the distance between my points on a line, as

```
line <-as(l, 'SpatialLines') 
points <- as(p, 'SpatialPoints') 
max.dist <-max(gDistance(points, line, byid=T)) #max distance to line
```

Problem: `gDistance` is no longer available because the `rgeos` package has been removed from the CRAN repository.

Is there an alternative function in the `sf` or `terra`, or others packages?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: See `terra::distance` or `sf::st_distance` for alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "distance" function of the terra package.

https://rdrr.io/cran/terra/man/distance.html